# Jenkins: Make file publicly available

Tags: ant, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am creating files with a custom version number during the build that I want to be publicly available through http.

Assuming I am building the project "MyTestApp", I want the version number text file I created to be available at a location like http://jenkins.company/job/MyTestApp/revision.txt

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David, this depends on what you mean by "publicly available".  If your Jenkins instance is secured (jenkins.company/configureSecurity/), then access to artifacts requires that your http session be authenticated. If all users who need access have accounts on the Jenkins server, then you just need to use the post-build action "archive the artifacts", and your text file would be available here: 
jenkins.company/job/MyTestApp/jobnumber/artifact/revision.txt

Or here:
jenkins.company/job/MyTestApp/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/revision.txt

See this screenshot: http://note.io/17oiykI

If you need unauthenticated access, you could publish your artifacts to another web server on the same or a different host. Or you could upload them to an Amazon S3 bucket.